# Allowing Two Developers Access to a Plugin on the WordPress.org Plugin Repository?

Tags: plugins, repository, wordpress.org

The question is "***How to Allow Two Developers Access to a Plugin on the
WordPress.org Plugin Repository?***"  This question was asked on the wp-hackers list and *@EAMann* answered it nicely and it's a great question to have here so I'm posting it for Eric to answer here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two (2) steps.

1. Add the WordPress.org username of the contributor you want to add to the
   "*contributors*" line in the header info of the Readme file, and that person 
   will have SVN commit access to the plugin.
2. Go to [the plugin repository](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins) and log in with the main account

   - Go to your plug-in and click the "*admin*" tab
   - Add the user's WordPress login name to the list of committers by entering their name and clicking "*Add Committer*."

That's it!